# Crystal Report 2008 export does not export Table correctly as table but every item & line as an object?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-export

I am working with Crystal Report 2008 but when I export my report my report in MS Word format the Table in report does not exported as Table but each line and item in table is exported as object.
[image]

Means you can not extend the column or row size other wise it behave like this

[image]

I want to export the table like table as in MS Word Table that you can Increase or Decrease Column or Row Height or width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always get a lot of problems while exporting crystal report to word/excel, I always got the same problem you have encountered.
I solved that problem by exporting dataset (report datasource) directly to excel, this solved all the issues, I've encountered.

I hope if this can match your requirements.

Please refer to this link for [Export a Dataset to Excel](http://tim.mackey.ie/HowtoExportADatasetToExcelCAspnet.aspx).